# Uitext Content SIze in UI Scroll View , the text in bottom is cut off

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have UIScroll that have uitextview inside it.

My apps look like this:

`rootviewcontroller` -> `PhoneContentController` (`UIScrollView` and `PageControl`) -> `DetailController` (`UITextView`, `UIWebView`, `UILabel`).

My Flow is like this:

Set `UIScrollView` default size -> call `DetailController` (calculate `UITextView` and other page inside it in `viewDidLoad`) -> `PhoneContentController` get the total height size from `DetailController`-> Change the height of `UIScrollView`

This is the code in `PhoneContentController` (`loadSCrollViewWithPage`):

```
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * kNumberOfPages, [detailController.getTotalHeight]);
```

The code in Detail Controller (`viewDidLoad`):

```
summaryBlogParsed = [summaryBlogParsed stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
[self.itemSummaryText setText:summaryBlogParsed];

CGRect frameTextView = self.itemSummaryText.frame;    

frameTextView.size.height = self.itemSummaryText.contentSize.height;

self.itemSummaryText.frame = frameTextView;
```

This code in `DetailController` `getTotalHeight`:

```
 CGRect cgRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

CGFloat scrollFrame = (cgRect.size.height/2) + itemSummaryText.frame.size.height;

                       return scrollFrame;
```

I can scroll the scrollview but the `textview` not load all of the string. like only half of it, but i can scroll down but with blank pages :(.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please try to explain this sentence in more detail, I don't know what you expect should happen and what actually happens: "I can scroll the scrollview but the textview not load all of the string. like only half of it, but i can scroll down but with blank pages :(."

Answer (score 0):

set content size of scroll view using this function.

```
-(void)setContentSizeOfScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scroll
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectZero;

    for(UIView * vv in [scroll subviews])
    {
        rect = CGRectUnion(rect, vv.frame);
    }

    [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
}
```

after adding all controls to your scroll view call this function and pass `yourScrollView` as argument. Hope this will help you.........

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple...  When debugging issues with text views, watch for this common pitfall:

Placing a text view inside of a scroll view. Text views handle their own scrolling. You should not embed text view objects in scroll views. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.