# UITextView cuts in the middle

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am having a problem with `UITextView`. On simulator it shows me the `UITextView` normally without any cut but when I run the project on real device, I am getting the cut in the middle.

```
self.popisakce.text = [self.objc objectForKey:@"Class"];
        [self.popisakce sizeToFit]; //added
        [self.popisakce layoutIfNeeded]; //added
        [self.popisakce sizeToFit];
        CGRect frame = self.popisakce.frame;
            CALayer *imageLayerRRR = self.popisakce.layer;
            [imageLayerRRR setCornerRadius:5];
            [imageLayerRRR setMasksToBounds:YES];

            UIScrollView* scrollview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,25,768, 900)];
            scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
            scrollview.scrollEnabled=YES;
            scrollview.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
            scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(768,frame.size.height+770);
```

Below is my output:

[image: link]

Comment: can u share your code please?

Comment: ops I forgot to. I updated the question

Comment: How long is your text? You can try setting the text programatically.

Comment: where is your textview framesize? how u add scrollview can u explain?

Comment: I am taking the text from parse.com. It`s sometimes some lines and sometimes large amount of text. I set the height of the text in the scrollview. I did it with label instead of UITextView and it worked normally

Comment: Textview framesize is in storyboards

Comment: Just use UITextView and anchor it to all sides.

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696706/large-text-being-cut-off-in-uitextview-that-is-inside-uiscrollview)

Comment: This bug I have right now just for large amount of text, The short one works normally

Comment: pawan Thanks,your post helped me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[textView setScrollEnabled:NO];` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

When you put text in a UITextView which is not visible, it may not be fully displayed.

Try moving the line `self.popisakce.text = [self.objc objectForKey:@"Class"];` lower in the code flow.

Comment: I m having problem right now just with the long one TextViews

Comment: Look at the solution above. The order in which you define the actions in Code is important. By changing the order, you can most certain solve this. 1) define 2) fill