# Cannot get correct UIScrollView height from its subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c

Inside the `viewDidLoad` of my `UIViewController` I create:

a `UIScrollView` with the following code:

```
- (void)generateScrollView {
    
    _scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:_containerView.frame];
    [_containerView addSubview:_scrollView];
    
    [self generateContentView];
    
}
```

Where `_containerView` is a `UIView` created through the Interface Builder with the following constraints:

[image]

Then I generate another `UIView` which i'll use as a container for all the UI Elements:

```
- (void)generateContentView {
    
    _contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:_scrollView.frame];
    
    [_scrollView addSubview:_contentView];
    
}
```

Then I generate N UI Elements (`UITextView`, `UIImageView` ecc..) and finally I recalculate the height of both the `contentView` and `scrollView` with the following code:

```
- (void)recalculateScrollViewHeight {
    
    CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *view in _contentView.subviews) {
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
        
        NSLog(@"ContentRect height: %f", contentRect.size.height);
    }
    
    _contentView.frame = CGRectMake(_contentView.frame.origin.x, _contentView.frame.origin.y, _contentView.frame.size.width, contentRect.size.height + [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame].size.height + self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height);
    
    NSLog(@"_contentView height: %f", _contentView.frame.size.height);
    
    _scrollView.contentSize = _contentView.frame.size;
    
}
```

The problem is that the `_scrollView` cuts some of the content because it seems that the calculated height its not correct. I'm struggling with this problem and I can't seem to find a solution, does anyone know why the calculated height it's not correct? Am I missing a property for the `UIScrollView` or `UIView`?

**EDIT**:
This is the result of the 2 `NSLog`:

> ContentRect height: 180.000000
>
> ContentRect height: 360.000000
>
> ContentRect height: 540.000000
>
> _contentView height: 604.000000

I've added 3 `UIImageView` with an height of `180` so the result is correct, 540 + 20 (status bar height) + 44 (navigation bar height), but still the `scrollView` cuts some pixels from the last image. Also there's no extra spacing between the images, they're one after another

Comment: can you print out the values of contentRect and _contentView.frame in the recalculate method ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I've edited the question with the NSLog

Comment: Instead of doing it in `viewDidLoad`, what happens if you do it in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: @trojanfoe DAMNNNN I tried to move in the viewDidAppear only the method that recalculated the height and it did not work, now I moved everything inside it and it works fine, thanks a lot you saved me hours :S

Comment: @trojanfoe if you want post it as an answer so I can accept! :)

Comment: @Signo It's a pretty common problem so I've marked the question as a dupe of one of them.

Comment: @trojanfoe Ok, thanks! I'm sorry for the duplicate but I wasn't able to find the existing question

Answer (score 1):

I've seen cases where a UIScrollView will try and be helpful by offsetting itself in order to incorporate the navigation bar even if it's hidden. Have you tried disabling this property?

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets
```

I assume you have scrollEnabled set to YES? This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I noticed others resolving similar issues here by disabling and re-enabling scrolling:

[Large Text Being Cut Off in UITextView That is Inside UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696706/large-text-being-cut-off-in-uitextview-that-is-inside-uiscrollview)