# UITextView does not start at top

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a modal screen with a `Page View`. The `Page View` loads the pages using storyboard IDs. All pages are the same. Each page has a `UITextView` with some text and its scrollable. At `viewDidLoad` the text is set. When the text is set, it automatically scrolls to bottom, so at `viewDidAppear` I invoke `[self.textField setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:animated];`.

This works fine, except for the first page. Due to a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696706/large-text-being-cut-off-in-uitextview-that-is-inside-uiscrollview), in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I need toggle `scrollEnabled` for the `UITextView`. However, when the first page is loaded, `viewDidAppear` is for some reason called prior to `viewLayoutSubviews`, which has the side-effect of scrolling the `UITextView` to bottom, probably due to the toggling. If I scroll past the first page and then return to first page, it works as expected (then the calling order is the same as for the other pages).

Some other things I've tried:

- Setting the text in `async_dispatch` on main queue in `viewDidLoad`.
- Calling `[self.textField scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];` at `viewDidLayoutSubviews`
- Various combinations of `scrollRangeToVisible` and `setContentOffset`.
- Setting `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` in `viewDidLoad`.
- Trying to scroll the view after setting the text (using either of the above methods)

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this?

Here is the code for the view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Get help string
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = <fetch text from external source>

    // Set text
    self.textField.attributedText = attributedString;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.textField setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    self.textField.scrollEnabled = NO;
    self.textField.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` is usually a good place to do last-minute adjustments before something shows up on screen, I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: Its a good guess, but in this case `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called after `viewWillAppear`, and the forced scrolling must be done after the layout (but for some reason not in layout callback). `viewDidAppear` is called after `viewDidLayoutSubviews`, so that works.

Comment: Your question title says `UITextView` but you repeatedly refer to `UITextField` in your question: which is it?

Comment: Whoops, good catch. Its supposed to be UITextView.

Comment: I just realized your code says 'fetch text from external source' - is this an async fetch that's taking a few milliseconds to complete?

Comment: No, it's just reading an RTF-file.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I'm loading a `UIViewController` with a `UITextView`. I assign the text in `viewDidLoad` and then set the `contentOffset` in `viewWillAppear`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textView.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda."
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        textView.contentOffset = .zero
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this work if you toggle `scrollEnabled` off and on in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: Yes. Maybe add more code with how your presenting the controllers or loading the text if you still have problems.